# How to set dropdownlist values to datatable

Tags: asp.net, database, dropdownbox

There is a list of items in `drop-down list`.I want to add those items in data table while selecting one by one item.How to do that? here i am giving my code.

```
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList li in ddlAssignedTo.Items)
            {
                if (li.SelectedItem ==checked)
                {
                    DataRow drUsers = dtAssigners.NewRow();
                    drUsers["GIMID"] = GIMID;
                    drUsers["MODE"] = 'I';
                    drUsers["UserId"] = Convert.ToInt32(li.SelectedValue);
                    drUsers["CreatedBy"] = CurUsr.UserId;
                    dtAssigners.Rows.Add(drUsers);
                }
            }
```

i am getting error near `(li.SelectedItem ==checked)`... can anyone help me?

Comment: There i am getting error..wht should i write instead of checked ?

Comment: write true instead of checked

Comment: For true also its showing error

Answer (score 0):

Example, if your drop down is like following:

You want to add first item in your table. You can do like:

```
if (ddl.SelectedValue == "1")
{
   //Write Your Code here
}
```

All these conditions will work using above DropDownList

```
if(ddl.SelectedValue == "1")
if(ddl.SelectedIndex == 0)
if (ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "One";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate the items in a dropdown to find the selected item.

```
var item = ddlAssignedTo.SelectedItem;

if (item != null)
                {
DataRow drUsers = dtAssigners.NewRow();
                    drUsers["GIMID"] = GIMID;
                    drUsers["MODE"] = 'I';
                    drUsers["UserId"] = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                    drUsers["CreatedBy"] = CurUsr.UserId;
                    dtAssigners.Rows.Add(drUsers);
                }
```

Edit: ok, if multiple items are selected, you can try this -

```
foreach (ListItem item in ddlAssignedTo.Items)
{
        if (item.Selected)
        {
        }
}
```

Edit 2: if your drop down list has checkboxes, you are most likely using the `checkboxlist` control.

The following code works fine for me. Please compare how you are setting up your data table.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("table1");
dt.Columns.Add("col1");
foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
     if (item.Selected)
     {
             names.Add(item.Text);
             DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
             dr["col1"] = item.Text;
             dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
 }
```

Comment: No its a multiselect drop-downlist.Its containing drop-down with checkbox list.so m choosing more than one item .So i think iteration is required.

Comment: But its storing only last checked item not all checked items.

Comment: please state clearly what should happen if item is selected. your question was about how to find if item is selected and not specific to iteration

Comment: My dropdown list contains a no of items with check box so we can select multiple items but while m trying with this code its storing in datatable only last selecetd item not all selected item.So where is my problem? Can you say?

Comment: Can you give me the code here..please..m doing dat but its nt working